# Eclipse's LogCat gets flooded with WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC with android

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I am writing a small android game, and whenever I first ran, everything worked fine, but it will randomly hang and start spamming this endlessly in eclipse's LogCat

> 12-30 12:40:05.344: D/dalvikvm(22831): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
>   12-30 12:40:05.383: D/dalvikvm(22831): GC_CONCURRENT freed 511K, 34% free 2374K/3552K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 14ms

I know it has something to do with garbage collecting, but whenever I force stop the app(the only way to close it) I lose around 5-10mb of available ram until I restart the device. does anyone know what this means and how to prevent it?

the device I am using is a verizon galaxy nexus running android 4.2.1(Cyanogenmod 10.1) and sdk/target version at 3.2(api level 13).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be able to Google your way into a much more detailed description, but basically it just means you're making the garbage collector work very hard.

Programming a game is different from programming a 'normal' app: your game probably loops countless of times. 
As a result of this even a tiny memory leak can grow quickly to a real problem.

Furthermore, GC is normall your biggest friend, in gaming it is pretty much one of your enemies. Every GC run creates a little freeze since it 'stops the world'.

I'd suggest you continue your search in specific gaming programming tutorials and how to work against the GC in those.

Comment: thanks, when you pointed out "loops countless times" it hit me that I should control the update and render thread's refresh rate

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but it's the first thing when I search for your error - [what does WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531657/what-does-wait-for-concurrent-gc-blocked-mean). Also, there's pretty much no reason to *target* 3.2